# How to run COM objects on a remote server in PHP

Tags: php, oop, dll, com, remote-server

How can I run a COM object that is located in a dll file on a remote server?

According to php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php#faq.com.q8):

> How can I run COM object from remote server ? Exactly like you run
>   local objects. You only have to pass the IP of the remote machine as
>   second parameter to the COM constructor.
>
> Make sure that you have set com.allow_dcom=TRUE in your php.ini.

I have com.allow_dcom enabled in my php.ini and according to phpinfo(); I do in fact have COM support, DCOM support, and .NET support enabled. I am having a hard time finding examples of how to call the remote objects.

The DLL file (pcmsrv32.dll) is located in C:\Windows on a remote server.
I need to access the object method CalcDistance() which is stored in that file.

I have tried to pass the file location and the IP to the COM class:

```
$obj = new COM("C:\Windows\PCMSRV32.DLL","10.86.0.21");
```

But that does not work. I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught com_exception: Failed to create COM object `C:\Windows\PCMSRV32.DLL': Moniker cannot open file in C:\Users\...\index.php:33
```

I have also tried using the ProgID given in the User Guide for PC*Miler|Connect and used that in my code:

```
$com = new COM("PCMServer.PCMServer.1","10.86.0.21");
```

However that gives me this error:

```
com_exception: Failed to create COM object `PCMServer.PCMServer.1': Invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Load DLL Stored on Remote Server in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42660347/how-to-load-dll-stored-on-remote-server-in-php)

Comment: I have deleted my other question as I am trying something different to solve my problem. I may end up deleting this one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting in touch with PC*Miler Support, and they gave me a sample code for making a basic call that can be run as a CLI script:

```
<?php 
  // Create COM Object 
  $pcms = new COM("PCMServer.PCMServer"); 
  // Calculate 
  $dist = $pcms->CalcDistance("12345","23456"); 
  // Returned distance is a INT that needs to be divided by 10 (or the number of decimal places specified in the PCMSServe.ini file located in C:\Windows 
  $properDist = ($dist/10); 

  echo $properDist 
?>
```

**EDIT**
I am now being told that PC*Miler only offers their COM objects locally. So unless I have it installed on the same server that I am developing on, this will not work. We are installing version 30 of PC*Miler to the same server where my PHP code resides and trying that instead.

**UPDATE**
We had v.30 of PC*Miler installed on the same server, as well as the patch that fixes a php bug, and I was able to successfully run the following code:

```
try {
    $pcms = new COM("PCMServer.PCMServer");
}
catch (com_exception $e) {
    print $e . "\n";
}
// Calculate
$dist = $pcms->CalcDistance("Goodyear, AZ","Las Vegas, NV");
$properDist = ($dist/10);
echo $properDist;
```

Output of `$properDist` was 288 miles - which I verified was correct with Google Maps.